# why is my query returning an EMPTY table?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

these are my tables and columns: 
Customers: customer#, lastname, firstname, address, city, state
Orders : Order#, customer#, orderdate, shipdate, shipaddress, shipcost

I m using SQL developer. 
question:
determine which order haven't yet shipped and the name of the customer who placed the order?
this is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT o.order#, o.orderdate, c.lastname, c.firstname,
FROM orders o JOIN customers c
ON c.customer#=o.customer#
WHERE o.shipdate= NULL
ORDER BY orderdate;
```

I get an empty table. I don't know why.
I removed the condition and tested the query and it worked but when I add the WHERE + condition, I get an empty table.
please help
thanks in advance

I have another question:
produce a list of all customers who live in Florida and have ordered books about computers. my query was

```
SELECT c.customer#, state, category
FROM customer c, orders o, orderitems oi, books b
WHERE c.customer#=0.customer#
AND o.order#=oi.order#
AND oi.isbn=b.isbn
AND c.state='FL'
AND b.category='computers';
```

I get error command not properly ended.
what is wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure that a "not shipped order" means orders.shipdate should be null?

Comment: i think so. that s the only meaning i can think of.

Answer (score 1):

I know for SQL Server when you check for null it has to be `value IS NULL` and not `value = NULL`. I just googled the syntax for Oracle DB and it seems to be the same. So try `o.shipdate IS NULL`.

For your second question, is this a typo? Looks like you have a zero instead of an O.

```
WHERE c.customer#=0.customer#
                  ^
WHERE c.customer#=o.customer#
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i changed the zero to 'o'. and i no loger have an error but i got a table with NO DATA in it.

Comment: you are right. i changed it to " is NULL " and it worked. thank you so much.